# How to bring search result to top of the v-carousel?

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js, z-index

I want to display search result beneath of the search box, but it goes behind the v-carousel.
I set CSS to v-card which displays the search result as follows:

```
z-index: 8;
width: 100vw;
top: 100%;
left: 0;
position: absolute;
```

[search result goes behind v-carousel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jubPG.png)

Comment: We need more infos about the markup/html structure. z-index does not automatically make your element the first in line. As it could be that the position context is wrong.

Comment: Thank you very much. it is solved, I just add z-index to v-card container, it means to v-toolbar. now v-card appears on top of v-carousel